# Confusion while using polar coordinates to solve a limit

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Given the function $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}{xe^\frac{x}{y}} \ \ y\neq0 \\ 0 \ \ y=0\end{cases}$, I wanted to find if the $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y)$ exists.

Obviously, when $y=0$ the limit of the restriction is $0$, then I used polar coordinates to find that $\lim_{p\rightarrow 0} \ p\cos(\theta)e^{\frac{cos(\theta)}{sin(\theta)}}=0$, but the trouble comes when I consider the restriction $y=x^2$, as in that case $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y)=\infty$, so I must be doing something wrong while using polar coordinates as the limit shouldn't exist, but I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: The limit using polar coordinates indeed does not exist: consider the restriction $\theta=p$ (with $p\to0^+$).

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

- The path $0\not=y=x$, then $xe^{x/y}=xe^{x/x}=xe\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.
- The path $0\not=y=x^{2}$, with $x\in ]0,+\infty[$, then $xe^{x/y}=xe^{1/x}\to +\infty$ as $x\to 0^{+}$.

Hence, $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exists because we found two path with different values of limit.

When, you change to polar coordinates you need the "form" $\displaystyle \lim_{p\to 0}f(p)g(r,\theta)$ but also you need two things $\displaystyle \lim_{p\to 0}f(p)=0$ and $\displaystyle g(r,\theta)$ to be bounded function. Of course in your case you have $f(p)=p$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{p\to 0}f(p)=0$, but the  problem is that the function $g(r,\theta)=\cos(\theta)e^{\cos(\theta)/\sin(\theta)}=\cos(\theta)e^{\cot(\theta)}$ is non-bounded. So, polar coordinates can not use here to conclude that the limit is zero.